# Flex checkBox: disable state change when clicked on label

Tags: apache-flex, checkbox

I would like the native Flex checkBox to **change state only**, when the **box is clicked**. If user clicks the label the state shouldn't change.

The click event cannot be muted as it is utilized in parenting components.

Any ideas how to obtain such functionality? How to **detect**, that user has **clicked the label**?

Thanks,
Rafal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Marty Pitt** was very close to the right answer. I've added an event handler to his code, that stops the propagation - and now it works perfectly (as expected)!

The code below is a class that extends `mx:CheckBox`:

```
        override protected function createChildren():void {
            super.createChildren();
            this.mouseChildren = true;
            textField.mouseEnabled = false;
            textField.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, textFieldClickHandler);
        }

        protected function textFieldClickHandler(me:MouseEvent):void{
            me.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Wow.  I'm really surprised that `MouseEvent.CLICK` fires when `mouseEnabled = false`.  That's not intuitive at all.  Still - I'm glad you found a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround - checkbox without label and separate label nearby.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a Halo checkbox, I would create a subclass, and override `createChildren()`, with something like:

```
override protected function createChildren():void {
     super.createChildren();
      // in Button, this is false by default, however we want to restrict
      // clicking to the button itself, not the label, so allow the children
      // to recieve mouse events, to prevent the button from dispatching them.
     this.mouseChildren = true;
     textField.mouseEnabled = false;
}
```

That seems like a pretty kludgy hack, but it may work (I haven't tested it).

If it's a Spark checkbox, then you can just create a seperate skin.  Much cleaner!

Comment: Thank you, it almost worked - I present the complete solution below.